# Error starting my project in Ruby On Rails(invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Every time I want to create a project in rails I get this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 83 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Writing lockfile to C:/laragon/www/project/Gemfile.lock
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  importmap:install
C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
You must either be running with node (package.json) or importmap-rails (config/importmap.rb) to use this gem.
```

Gem Env:

```
C:\Users\Javier Franco>gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.10
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 patchlevel 53) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Javier Franco/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Javier Franco/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby32-x64/bin/ruby.exe
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: C:\laragon\bin\git\bin/git.EXE
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Javier Franco/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Javier Franco/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x64-mingw-ucrt
  - GEM PATHS:
     - C:/Users/Javier Franco/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
     - C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => ["--install-dir", "C:/Users/Javier Franco/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0", "--bindir", "C:/Users/Javier Franco/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - C:\Ruby32-x64\bin
     - C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.7.7-hotspot\bin
     - C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
     - C:\WINDOWS\system32
     - C:\WINDOWS
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
     - C:\Program Files (x86)\D-Link\Central WifiManager\php5
     - C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
     - C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64
     - C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v18
     - C:\laragon\bin\yarn\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10
     - C:\laragon\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\apache\httpd-2.4.54-win64-VS16\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\composer
     - C:\laragon\bin\git\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\git\cmd
     - C:\laragon\bin\git\mingw64\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\git\usr\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\laragon\utils
     - C:\laragon\bin\mysql\mysql-8.0.30-winx64\bin
     - C:\laragon\bin\nginx\nginx-1.22.0
     - C:\laragon\bin\ngrok
     - C:\laragon\bin\nodejs\node-v18
     - C:\laragon\bin\notepad++
     - C:\laragon\bin\php\php-8.1.10-Win32-vs16-x64
     - C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10
     - C:\laragon\bin\python\python-3.10\Scripts
     - C:\laragon\bin\redis\redis-x64-5.0.14.1
     - C:\laragon\bin\telnet
     - C:\laragon\bin\yarn\bin
     - C:\laragon\usr\bin
     - C:\Users\Javier Franco\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\.bin
     - C:\Users\Javier Franco\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
     - C:\Users\Javier Franco\AppData\Roaming\npm
     - C:\Users\Javier Franco\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
     - C:\sqlite
     - C:\Ruby32-x64\bin
```

I was looking for possible solutions and I found that the error may be in the Ruby Executable because in some forums from 10 years ago they comment that there is an error with the space although I think the problem may be caused because my Ruby Executable is not inside double quotes ( "...") and I don't know how to change them

I've been trying to fix this error for 2 weeks, I hope you can help me.

Try uninstalling Ruby and reinstalling it. I also ran the command from cmd as administrator but I always get that error.

Comment: I'm using Ruby version 3.2.2 and on Rails 7.1.2.

Comment: Are you running node or importmap-rails for the project?

Comment: I have installed nodejs, yarn and everything necessary to run my project in rails but it always gives me this error 'C:\Ruby32-x64\bin\ruby.exe: invalid switch in RUBYOPT: -F (RuntimeError)'

Comment: First of all, I suggest you to install rvm. Then, if you are on rails 7 and you are using importmaps (you really should), then you don't need node, yarn, npm etc...
Is it possibile that you have more than one ruby installed, try to run `which ruby` and check